# weak_ptr reset affects shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++17, smart-pointers, visual-studio-2019, icc

I'm not very used to using `weak_ptr` and I'm facing a quite confusing situation. I'm using **Intel XE 2019 Composer update 5** (*package 2019.5.281*) in combinaison with **Visual Studio 2019 ver. 16.2.5**. I compile in 64-bit. I use the standard **C++ 17**.

Here is the code for my spike solution:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    shared_ptr<int> sp = make_shared<int>( 42 );
    cout << "*sp = " << *sp << endl;

    weak_ptr<int> wp = sp;
    cout << "*sp = " << *sp << ", *wp = " << *wp.lock() << endl;

    wp.reset();
    cout << "*sp = " << *sp << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output I expected to have is:

```
*sp = 42
*sp = 42, *wp = 42
*sp = 42
```

...but here is what I obtained:

```
*sp = 42
*sp = 42, *wp = 42
*sp = -572662307
```

What is goin on? Is it normal for the `shared_ptr` to be modified/invalidated when the/an associated `weak_ptr` is reset? I'm a little confused about the results I obtained. To say the truth I didn't expect this result...

## EDIT 1

While the bug occurs in **64-bit** configuration, it doesn't in **32-bit**. In this later configuration, the result is what is expected.

## EDIT 2

The bug occurs only in **Debug**. When I build in **Release**, I get the expected result.

Comment: [cannot repro on g++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3cc3fd07a4975c6c) and [cannot repro on clang++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08a48e394cfa5ba4)

Comment: I think your implementation has a bug.  [gcc produces the correct results](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/061907233fdc16ab)

Comment: Cannot reproduce in Visual Studio 2019 (v. 16.2.5)

Comment: No, this definitely is not normal.

Comment: If you change your last `cout` to `cout << "sp->use_coutn() = " << sp->use_count() << endl;`, what do you get?

Comment: Cannot repro on `icc 19.0.0` or `icc 19.0.1`: https://godbolt.org/z/nr7LnH (older versions either don't know `shared_ptr` or run into trouble with `ld`). Can you share the exact compiler flags used?

Comment: In case it helps debug, `-572662307 = 0xDDDDDDDD`, which is msvc's way of indicating freed heap memory

Comment: @NathanOliver `sp.use_count()` gives 0xDDDDDDDD or -57...

Comment: Do you still get the same behavior if you remove the `wp.lock()` call ?

Comment: @dom_beau If you remove the `wp.reset();` line, does that change what `cout << "sp->use_coutn() = " << sp->use_count() << endl;` displays?

Comment: @MaxLanghof Compiler flags are `/GS /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /ZI /Od /Fd"x64\Debug\vc142.pdb" /fp:precise /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /MDd /std:c++17 /FC /Fa"x64\Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Debug\" /Qprof-dir "x64\Debug\" /Fp"x64\Debug\weakptr.pch" `

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Actually yes. The problem comes probably from the `.reset()`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, if I remove the `.reset()`, the `.use_count()` becomes 1. And of course the last `cout` prints the correct value 42.

Comment: Weird.  That is a heck of a bug.

Comment: @NathanOliver "That is a heck of a bug." For me or for Intel?

Comment: Something in your implementation (compile/library).

Comment: Note that `*wp.lock()` happens before  `*sp`, Code `int i = 15; cout << i << " " << ++i << endl;` would output `16 16`. It's dangerous to use side-effects within stream output.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie: C++17 guaranties some ordering for `E1 << E2` (so output is guarantied to be `15 16`). (see [evaluation_order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) #19)

Comment: @Jarod42 Microsoft and Intel compilers absolutely disregard that, just tested it.Olso, technically << is opposite of + in association.

Comment: The ordering doesn't matter in this case.  Any order will produce the same results.

Comment: @NathanOliver you're right, of course and it's a bug. Except in cases like this static analyzer of compiler may consider UB.   experimental versions of gcc warn about possible UB when it detects side-effect.

Answer (score 2):

It appears it is a real bug on Intel ICC side; I have reported it.

Thanks again for helping me to pin-point this problem.

Comment: Could you add a link to the bug report in your answer ? That way, anyone with the same issue can be referred to the bug report for its status.

Comment: I'll rather add a comment once the case will be fixed.

Comment: Yes please to adding the link - this will allow readers to add their own remarks to the report.

Comment: Don't see how. If you reach the link, you need an Intel account to see it??? Maybe I'm wrong??? Tell me... I opened a ticket and it is in my account.

Comment: Maybe you can reach the discussion I'm having in the forum: [C++ compiler forum](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-c-compiler/topic/827586)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bug in debug library, with sentinel values.It's easy to check, by using line I mentioned:

```
int i = 1; cout << i << " " << ++i << endl;
```

If output is `2 2` instead of `1 2`, then compiler is not compliant and possibly still considers such case an UB. Sentinel values may be used erroneously in this case with call of `reset()`. Similar thing happens with deleting object created by placement new within preallocated static buffer, in debug mode it gets overwritten by some implementations with sentinel values.

Comment: It gives `1 2` in both **64-bit** and **32-bit**, **Debug** and **Release**.

Comment: The bug is in `_Ref_count_base` default cTor which is specified `= default`. The two members `_Uses = 1` and `_Weaks = 1` are set to `1` and `0` respectively. It seems that the default generated cTor is bugged. See the `memory` file...

Comment: @dom_beau well,it is worth of a report, also we know that Initialization in C++ is [Seriously Bonkers](http://mikelui.io/2019/01/03/seriously-bonkers.html)